# How to remove slash "/" in string in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a string like "http://example.com/a/b/c". I want to transform the string to "httpexamplecomabc" in order to save it as the file name. I have tried

```
let result = str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "//"))
```

and

```
let result = str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "/"))
```

but neither works. Any Idea on how to remove "/"? Thanks

Comment: Note that this leaves you open to ambiguity if you have two files http://example.com/ab/c and http://example.com/a/bc which will compress to the same filename by your design.

Comment: That is a good comment. Maybe we can replace / with _ but the things is it seems I cannot make swift to find those slash /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace occurrence of  "/ " to "" by using

```
let mm = "http://example.com/a/b/c"

let newString = mm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("/", withString: "")
print(newString) // http:example.comabc
```

Comment: @AnsonYao: Not weird at all, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1415462-stringbytrimmingcharactersinset) is quite clear: "Returns a new string made by removing from *both ends* of the receiver characters contained in a given character set."

Comment: @MartinR, You are right. It seems I misunderstand the term "trim" as "remove"... As a word,  "trim" is supposed to work only on the ends.